# How to display WellKnownText in google-map

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I am currently using the goolge maps angular component and have the following that works perfectly.
The problem is that my data is not in the format that they use which is ....

```
polygons: [{path: [{latitude: x, longitude: y },...]
```

but in WellKnownText (WKT) format like:

```
POLYGON ((y x,...))
```

Is there some way of getting the google maps to display the WKT format instead?

This is what I currently have and works perfectly well:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.coordinates" zoom="map.zoom" options="options">
    <ui-gmap-polygon 
        ng-repeat="poly in map.polygons"
        path='poly.path'
        fill='poly.fill'
        stroke='poly.stroke'
        clickable='poly.clickable'
        draggable='poly.draggable'
        editable='poly.editable'>
    </ui-gmap-polygon>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

The angularjs controller looks like this

```
$scope.map = {
        visible: false,
        coordinates: _startingCoordinates,
        zoom: _zoom,
        bounds: {},
        polygons: [{
            path: [
                { latitude: 52.39786758957449, longitude: -9.951156616210937 },
                { latitude: 52.38278195910962, longitude: -9.848846435546875 },
                { latitude: 52.32028936800865, longitude: -9.855026245117187 },
                { latitude: 52.30517723258029, longitude: -9.896911621093750 },
                { latitude: 52.24635875956514, longitude: -9.868072509765625 },
                { latitude: 52.26863493471054, longitude: -9.999908447265625 },
                { latitude: 52.33749412738444, longitude: -9.986175537109375 },
                { latitude: 52.34714264824414, longitude: -10.05895996093750 }
            ],
            fill: {
                color: "#00f274",
                opacity: 0.4
            },
            stroke: {
                color: "#cacaca",
                weight: 1,
                opacity: .8
            },
            visible: true,
        }]
    };
```

Maybe there's a setting or option in the google API, but I can't find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try parsing the WKT String using a custom function. Some examples could be seen here: [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59330/how-to-use-wkt-in-google-map-v3)

Comment: yes I figured that was the way to do it alright. Just thought there was a neater way of implementing it. Thanks